# How to for loop throughout a list of strings inside two nested loops and avoid redundancy caused by the outer loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested-loops

[image: screenshot]

What I'm trying to do is to print each translation at a time, but all what's getting printed now is the whole list of translated items each time in each loop.

```
"""
pure_data = string
transliterate_input = string
stemmed_tokens = list of dictionaries, each dictionary: key:string, value:list
translation: list of strings
"""

def parse_results(pure_data, transliterated_input, stemmed_tokens, translation):
    try:
        formatted_strings = []
        footer = "-"*50
        for d in stemmed_tokens:
            for k, v in d.items():
                found_stem = uni2ma(k)
                token_string = f"[{' + '.join([token for token in v])}]"
                translated = f"{[t for t in translation]}"
                word_string = f"original input:\n{pure_data}\nTransliterated Input:\n{transliterated_input}\nFound stem:\n{found_stem}\nparsed_results:\n {token_string}\n {translated}\n{footer}\n"
                formatted_strings.append(word_string)
        return '\n'.join(formatted_strings)
    except:
            final_str = 'There was a problem retrieving that information'
```

Edit:
Let's assume I have an input: House of cards.

It gets splitted into 3 strings, this three different inputs, each processed accordingly. But when it comes to the "Translation" part, instead of printing only the first, second or third value each time, e.g.

```
Translation: House
Translation: of
Translation: cards
```

It prints:

```
Translation: house of cards
Translation: house of cards 
Translation: house of cards
```

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I'm unclear about your requirement, can you give a sample output to show what you want to improvement, or point out the exsit problem in current impementation?

Comment: If you see the image above, the output produced is two groups of values separated by dashes ---------.  Each of the groups is the result of the first string of the input. The input is each string separated by white space.E.g. we have 3 inputs, we get 3 groups of outputs separated with the dashes. Everything is fine until the "Translation" output which just prints the whole list of strings instead of printing string1 for group output1, string2 for group output2, stringN for group outputN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply achieve your goal by using index to get corresponding element in translation, instead of:

```
translated = f"{[t for t in translation]}"
```

change to:

```
idx = 0
for d in stemmed_tokens:
    for k, v in d.items():        
        ...
        translated = translation[idx]
        ...
        idx += 1
```

Didn't know whether I get misunderstanding or not.

Comment: yeah, it is simple, so I'm confused about what you really want. @MurphyAdam

Comment: btw, maybe the original input, you want to split either? @MurphyAdam

Comment: Yes! Almost missed it. I think I could achieve the same result with the same trick?

Comment: yeah, use `split` first